# Vue not defined even though it's been imported

Tags: javascript, npm, import, vue.js, require

So I have installed vuejs using npm:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2"
}
```

And I have also imported it in my file:

```
import "vue"

const app = new Vue({

    el: "#app",
    template: `

        <div>
            <h1>Siddharth Knows It All</h1>
        </div>

    `

});
```

But the problem that I'm facing is that when I compile the code using webpack and run it on a local server, in the console it outputs `Vue is not defined`.

The console also outputs

> You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
>   production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
>   https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it possible that it should be `import Vue from 'vue'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you should be using:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

It might be worthwhile to take a moment to read how the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement actually works.

---

What you are doing essentially is importing the module for its side effects only:

> **Import a module for its side effects only**
>
> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing
>   anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually
>   import any values.
>
> `import '/modules/my-module.js';`

What you want to be doing is import the default `export` of the module:

> **Importing defaults**
>
> It is possible to have a default export (whether it is an object, a
>   function, a class, etc.). The import statement may then be used to
>   import such defaults.
>
> `import myDefault from '/modules/my-module.js';`